# How to update connection metadata in client-side store?

Tags: relayjs

I'm attempting to learn Relay by implementing TodoMVC from scratch.
I can query my data like this which is working well:

```
query {
  allTodos(first: 100) {
    totalCount
    completedCount
    edges {
      node {
        id
        text
        completed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the idea to add the `totalCount` and `completedCount` metadata to the connection from here: http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/#end-of-list-counts-and-connections
It's similar in this example: https://github.com/graphql/swapi-graphql/blob/master/src/schema/index.js#L78

Now I am writing a mutation to change the `completed` field of a `Todo` given its `id`.
I gather I will need to return the new `completedCount` in the mutation payload, but I'm not sure how to implement `getConfigs()` to update this in the client-side store. I don't have an `id` for the connection, right? Is there is a flaw in my schema design? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your mutation returns a `viewer`, you'll need to add the `viewer` to your `fatQuery` and `getConfigs`.  I think [this tutorial](https://www.reindex.io/docs/tutorial/adding-mutations/#addtodomutation) might be helpful. Here's the excerpt relevant to your task:

> Adding a Todo is more complex. The reason for this is that we need to
>   update not only the state of a Todo object that we will create, but
>   also a connection where it is stored - the count of Todos will change,
>   as well as the listing of Todo nodes in edges.
>
> ```
> import Relay from 'react-relay';
>
> export default class AddTodoMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
>   static fragments = {
>     viewer: () => Relay.QL`fragment on ReindexViewer {
>       id
>       allTodos {
>         count,
>       }
>     }`
>   };
>
>   getMutation() {
>     return Relay.QL`mutation{ createTodo }`;
>   }
>
>   getVariables() {
>     return {
>       text: this.props.text,
>       complete: false,
>     };
>   }
>
>   getFatQuery() {
>     return Relay.QL`
>       fragment on _TodoPayload {
>         changedTodoEdge,
>         viewer {
>           id,
>           allTodos {
>             count
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     `;
>   }
>
>   getConfigs() {
>     return [{
>       type: 'RANGE_ADD',
>       parentID: this.props.viewer.id,
>       connectionName: 'allTodos',
>       edgeName: 'changedTodoEdge',
>       rangeBehaviors: {
>         '': 'prepend',
>       },
>     }, {
>       type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
>       fieldIDs: {
>         viewer: this.props.viewer.id,
>       },
>     }];
>   }
>
>   getOptimisticResponse() {
>     return {
>       changedTodoEdge: {
>         node: {
>           text: this.props.text,
>           complete: false,
>         },
>       },
>       viewer: {
>         id: this.props.viewer.id,
>         allTodos: {
>           count: this.props.viewer.allTodos.count + 1,
>         },
>       },
>     };
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In order to perform this mutation, we need some data that might not be
>   available to the component - the id of viewer object and count of
>   allTodos connection. Therefore we need to specify fragments for the
>   mutation same way as we specify them for containers.
>
> Our configs are more complex this time too - we need to add our new
>   Todo to a connection, so we use RANGE_ADD mutation config. Relay
>   expects an edge to be passed in payload, not just a Todo, Reindex
>   provides changedTodoEdge for this. Lastly we need to fetch updated
>   connection count from the server and for this viewer field is
>   available for every payload.
>
> In our optimistic update we increment the count of allTodos, so that
>   we change our “total” display without any delay.